# St.TextureCache overflowing St.Bin in gnome-shell JS

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I'm trying to make a gnome-shell extension where I need to load an image from an URL / URI.
I can do that with `St.TextureCache` and that works great. I then try to put it in an `St.Bin` container, but the texture overflows the container (as shown in the screenshot). Is there a way (CSS maybe?) such that this does not happen?

The reason I want that is to give the image rounded corners, with the idea that I can give rounded corners easily to the `St.Bin` with CSS but it seems I can't style the texture directly. If there is another way to round the corners of the image that is also fine

A screenshot showing the problem. The `St.Bin` has a red border, but the texture clearly overflows it

[image: screenshot]

The relevant code:

```js
let file = Gio.File.new_for_uri(url_to_picture);
let bin = new St.Bin({
            style_class: 'icon-custom',
            y_expand: false,
            y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.START,
            visible: true,
            });
            
let texture = St.TextureCache.get_default().load_file_async(file, -1, 120, 1, 1);
bin.set_child(texture);
```

and CSS:

```css
.icon-custom {
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with your library, but pure css: if you apply overflow hidden on the container, and the image is a child of the container, it would 'fit' ;)